# Are the vector subspaces equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ be elements of a vector space.

Does it hold that $\langle 2v_1, 3v_2, \frac{1}{2}v_2+v_3, -3v_4\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2, v_3, v_3+v_4\rangle$ ?

Or is one of them a subspace of the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal"?

Comment: I mean that the sets of the corresponding linear combinations are equal. Can that be? @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: Does it hold that $\langle 2v_1, 3v_2, \frac{1}{2}v_2+v_3, -3v_4\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2, \frac{1}{2}v_2+v_3, v_4\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2, -\frac{1}{2}v_2+\frac{1}{2}v_2+v_3, v_4\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\rangle$ ? @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: So you're asking if the two sets form bases for the same space?

Comment: Yes. @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about sets of vectors that form bases for subspaces?

Comment: I tried to write a vector x as a linear combination of both bases. That is opssible, or not? @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: What else do we have to check? @MichaelMcGovern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Both are equal to $\langle v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\rangle$. 
In general, with a subspace $U$,  for $\langle a_1,a_2,\dots\rangle\subseteq U$ it's enough to show that each $a_i\in U$, and equality of sets $U=V$ is implied by $U\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq U$.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-)